# How do you know when a bounty has been awarded?

Tags: support, faq, bounties

Is it possible to know when a bounty has been awarded from an answer? Is there any graphic element that shows which answer has received the bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the bounty is awarded, the answer that won will have a red box underneath its score.

> [image: screenshot]

You can also confirm where the bounty went (or if it was awarded at all) by checking the question's revision history. For example, on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/17278/revisions), the bounty was not awarded, as noted by *Bounty Ended with no winning answer*.

> [image: Bounty not awarded]

On [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/31121/revisions), the bounty was awarded, as noted by *Bounty Ended with [Clive's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-automatically-upload-images-on-file-selection-rather-than-pressing-the/31453#31453) chosen by [Patrick Kenny](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/5147/patrick-kenny)*.

> [image: Bounty awarded]

A bounty is not awarded if:

- The user who offered the bounty didn't manually award the bounty
- There isn't any answer for which the bounty can be automatically awarded, which means there isn't any answer posted after the bounty started whose score is at least 2 when the bounty ends

If the bounty if offered from the user who asked the question, the bounty is automatically awarded to the accepted answer, if the answer has been accepted after the bounty was offered.